# "No media found". How to insert image in android

Tags: android

I am new to android programming so I will be really grateful if someone helps me.

I am trying to implement steganography in android but my problem is I don't know how to insert images in android. Because of which I am getting `"No media found"`. Please help me with this.

I tried

> c:> adb push c:\image1.png /sdcard/image1.png

But I get this in the Command Prompt.

> failed to copy 'c:\image1.png' to 'sdcard/image1.png' : Read-only file system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct directory for my emulator is `mnt/sdcard`. This works for me:

```
adb push README mnt/sdcard
```

Also note that you can explore directories using `adb shell ls <path>`, which might have tipped you off to the right path.

**Edit** - apparently `sdcard` is a symlink to `mnt/sdcard` and works for me as well. Using a file named `image1.png` is also working. Maybe there is a problematic file already located at that location for you?

**Edit 2** - I think you also need to have the USB mounting option turned off when you use adb to push files. It sounds like you have this on given your comment about the gallery not finding your media.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...actually the above code which i gave works for videos...i don't know why its not working for images. ...Also adding is there any other method to add images in android programming...as even if i am seeing my gallery its showing the same i.e. "No media found". I am new to android programming...so somebody please help.

Comment: Are you using the mount sdcard option? If you're going to use adb I think this needs to be off.

Comment: Thanks again for helping..actually i don't know how to check the mount sdcard option. Also god bless you

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, so in case anyone lands on this page here is how I solved it

1. When creating the emulator device (I use IntelliJ IDEA) - do not forget to move the radio button on SDCard option to the Size option, and specify the needed size, this way a new SDCard will be created and mounted to the emulator. In eclipse there are some command line parameters you can pass (or something else, I am not sure, since I read it only on the stackoverflow).
2. After that I stopped receiving the "Read-only file system" error, but I tried and tried and tried copying the files to the sdcard using:
   adb push image.jpg /sdcard/image.jpg
   or
   adb push image.jpg /mnt/sdcard/image.jpg
   but was receiving "No media found" error in my app or when I went to the gallery.
   So I went to Dev Tools on the emulator applications, then to the Media Scanner. It quickly scanned the sdcard, and boom - I finally got to see my images.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This was the ticket for me: "So I went to Dev Tools on the emulator applications, then to the Media Scanner. It quickly scanned the sdcard, and boom - I finally got to see my images."

Comment: Thankzz a lot ksu..., I went through so many materials for this answer... But only u could save me..

Comment: At first I thought "Dev Tools" was under the emulator view in Eclipse DDMS.  Then I realized it's an app you run from the emulator (no eclipse after the images are copied into the emulator folder!).  Yes, this totally saved the day, thanks!

Comment: five years later, and this still saves people!! thanks man !!

Comment: When I did the scan the Dev Tools Crash .. but after restarting the emulator the images was shown